# Does anyone knows any technique to find the location of an object in an image?

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, computing, deep-learning

We are doing a project in which we are detecting (using YOLOv4) runway debris using a fixed camera mounted at a pole on the side of the runway. We want to find out the position of the object with respect to the runway surface. Does anyone know about any algorithm or technique that will help us find out the position of the object with respect to runway dimensions?